# Why does jetty running in docker return 502 Bad Gateway when the proxy module is enabled?

Tags: docker, jetty, reverse-proxy

Run a simple jetty docker container:

`docker run --rm -it -p 8080:8080 jetty:9.4`

Request the root WebApp URL:

`curl -I http://localhost:8080`

Response, as expected, is 404, since there is no root WebApp:

`HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
Cache-Control: must-revalidate,no-cache,no-store
Content-Type: text/html;charset=iso-8859-1
Content-Length: 317
Server: Jetty(9.4.11.v20180605)`

Now start a jetty docker container with the proxy module enabled:

`docker run --rm -it -p 8080:8080 jetty:9.4 --module=proxy`

Request the same Root URL:

`curl -I http://localhost:8080`

Response is HTTP 502 Bad Gateway:

`HTTP/1.1 502 Bad Gateway
Cache-Control: must-revalidate,no-cache,no-store
Content-Type: text/html;charset=iso-8859-1
Server: Jetty(9.4.11.v20180605)
Content-Length: 321`

Why? I cannot get a jetty docker container running the proxy module to serve any webapps or content.
Running: Docker Version 18.06.1-ce-mac73 (26764)

Answer (score 0):

Proxy module is for Jetty itself to act as a proxy to another webserver.

Just enabling it results in an empty configuration where it has no destination to talk to, hence the `502 Bad Gateway`.